# Implement MySQL on basic long polling example

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to create a test application to retrieve a message after insert new data to the database, it's a basic "long polling", i followed and used the files from this [example](https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling), but this script only gets data from a file named "data.txt", how can i use the same logic and get the data from the database as soon i inserta new one?

here's the php code:

```
set_time_limit(0);

// where does the data come from ? In real world this would be a SQL query or something
$data_source_file = 'data.txt';

// main loop
while (true) {

    // if ajax request has send a timestamp, then $last_ajax_call = timestamp, else $last_ajax_call = null
    $last_ajax_call = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : null;

    // PHP caches file data, like requesting the size of a file, by default. clearstatcache() clears that cache
    clearstatcache();
    // get timestamp of when file has been changed the last time
    $last_change_in_data_file = filemtime($data_source_file);

    // if no timestamp delivered via ajax or data.txt has been changed SINCE last ajax timestamp
    if ($last_ajax_call == null || $last_change_in_data_file > $last_ajax_call) {

        // get content of data.txt
        $data = file_get_contents($data_source_file);

        // put data.txt's content and timestamp of last data.txt change into array
        $result = array(
            'data_from_file' => $data,
            'timestamp' => $last_change_in_data_file
        );

        // encode to JSON, render the result (for AJAX)
        $json = json_encode($result);
        echo $json;

        // leave this loop step
        break;

    } else {
        // wait for 1 sec (not very sexy as this blocks the PHP/Apache process, but that's how it goes)
        sleep( 1 );
        continue;
    }
}
```

jquery code: client.js

```
function getContent(timestamp)
{
    var queryString = {'timestamp' : timestamp};
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/long_polling/server/server.php',
            data: queryString,
            success: function(data){
                // put result data into "obj"
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                // put the data_from_file into #response
                $('#response').html(obj.data_from_file);
                // call the function again, this time with the timestamp we just got from server.php
                getContent(obj.timestamp);
            }
        }
    );
}

// initialize jQuery
$(function() {
    getContent();
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the php error log and the javascript console? (F12)

Comment: Think of it like this: a file is nothing more than a series of records (lines) and a database is the same. For a database you have two ways of going about it. Example one: If the current table has 10 records(rows) all you have to do is check if a new record was inserted by counting the records, if there are 11 then there is new data. Example two: if a record was updated then there is different data.

Comment: i'm not getting any error, the script works just fine, i just dont know how to put the database on it;

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP:
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$result = array();

while (true) {
    clearstatcache();

    // if you using database, don't forget fill the fields
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;", "", "");
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $query->execute();

    /**
     * Not necessary to use output from database.
     * If you want use data in text file, you can use this solution:
     *
     * $data = file_get_contents('data.php');
     * $result['data'] = $data;
     * echo $result['data'];
     *
     */
    
    // fields from database
    while ($fetch = $query->fetch()) {
        $result['id'] = $fetch['id'];
        $result['name'] = $fetch['name'];
        $result['message'] = $fetch['message'];
        echo "id: " . $result['id'] . "<br>";
        echo "name: " . $result['name'] . "<br>";
        echo "message: " . $result['message'] . "<br>";
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.